# Knight's tour in C++

Tags: c++, knights-tour

I have this knight's tour problem that I have to solve. I have to input a NxN matrix and the coordinates of the knight, where (1 , 1) is the bottom left element. Now the program works correctly, however my problem is that the task states that there can be many inputs. That's why I've added a while loop in the main function (to continuously take inputs and solve them, however after the first input the program doesn't let me write anymore in the console (as if it blocks out), and the only thing I can do is stop the console. Can you please help me with my problem? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXN = 10;
const int MAXD = 10;

const int maxDiff = 8;

const int diffX[MAXD] = { 1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -2, 2, -2 };
const int diffY[MAXD] = { 2, -2, 2, -2, 1, 1, -1, -1 };

unsigned board[MAXN][MAXN];
unsigned newX, newY;

void printBoard(int n)
{
int i, j;
for (i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            cout << board[i - 1][j];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " " << board[i - 1][j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}

void nextMove(int X, int Y, int i, int n)
{
int k;
board[X][Y] = i;
if (i == n * n) 
{ 
    printBoard(n); 
    return; 
}

for (k = 0; k < maxDiff; k++)
{
    newX = X + diffX[k]; newY = Y + diffY[k];
    if ((newX >= 0 && newX < n && newY >= 0 && newY < n) && (0 ==             board[newX][newY]))
    {
        nextMove(newX, newY, i + 1, n);
    }
}
board[X][Y] = 0;
}

int main()
{
int n;
int startX;
int startY;
int br = 0;
while (cin >> n >> startX >> startY)
{
    if (n < 4 || n > 10)
    {
        break;
    }
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    nextMove(startX - 1, startY - 1, 1, n);
}
return 0;
}
```

Edit: Apparently I mistook the conditions. The matrix should be 2 < n < 10. However when I change the condition the program doesn't work for matrix lower than 5. Any idea what's wrong with it?

Comment: A few pointers: variable length arrays are a no-no. Comparing signed and unsigned values is also a no-no.

Comment: Use a debugger.  Which test cases fail?  What are the expected outputs / behavior?  What is the actual outputs / behavior?  Which statement is causing the issue?  Please edit your question with the answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. The knight's tour is a special case of Hamiltonian path problem is NP-hard in general.Heuristic is able to successfully locate a solution in linear time.
2. for m × n board with m ≤ n, a closed knight's tour is always possible unless one or more of these three conditions are met.

   - m and n are both odd
   - m = 1, 2, or 4
   - m = 3 and n = 4, 6, or 8.[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour)

You are using bruit-force approach. Hence it stuck in cases where it will not find the solution.

> after the first input the program doesn't let me write anymore

because `nextMove()` continues to execute after finding the solution . You should place flag

```
if (i == n * n) 
{ 
    printBoard(n); 
    global_flag=true;
    return; 
}
```

and check this flag in

```
if ((newX >= 0 && newX < n && newY >= 0 && newY < n) && (0 == board[newX]newY]))
{
    nextMove(newX, newY, i + 1, n);
    if(global_flag) return;
}
```

initialize `global_flag=false` in while loop

Comment: Why does `i` need to be global?  Can it be passed by reference instead?